# Spark Dataframe like structure in another Scala library

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Do we have another library that has a 2D matrix(table) structure like Spark dataframe and allows SQL queries on it?

I don't want to use spark because I am not going to make it parallel + it is heavy.

Comment: A Map[String, Iterator[Any]] would be something similar to a DF